# Surface integral of a cone-plane intersection - what was I missing?

Tags: calculus

The problem states:

Given a cone $Co:3z^2 = x²+y²$ and a plane $\pi: z = \sqrt3$, find the area given by $\iint_CdS$ for a $C$ where $Co\leq\pi$ and $z \geq 0$.

So this is a surface area problem. But the answer I find is not available as a possible answer, which are either $\sqrt 3 \pi, 6 \pi, 3 \pi,$ or $ 6 \sqrt 3 \pi$.
The answer I get is $4 \sqrt 3 \pi$. What did I miss?

This is what I was doing: found a $z=g(x,y)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{3}}$ , computed the partials $g_x=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and $g_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$.

Applying it to this formula below:[image: integral used]

I got the result $\iint_C\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}dA$ and parameterized the curve with polar coordinates $x=rcos\theta, y=rsin\theta$ and plugged in the value of $z=\sqrt3$ to the $Co$ to find $r$, which gave me $0\leq r\leq3$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.
Applying these limits to the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}drd\theta$ would yield $4 \sqrt 3 \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is rather simple, really. I was missing the Jacobian, which in the case of a polar coordinate transformation, is simply $r$, which then when we evaluate the, now correct, integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^3\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}rdrd\theta$ will yield the answer $6\sqrt3 \pi$.

Since I realized that simple mistake as I was typing this question, I suppose the real lesson here is recognizing when to switch gears from grinding a solution to a problem from scratch over and over to taking a step back and evaluating your approach.